# JS How to make the list item slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to make a retractable menu, when the user touches an item it should slide on the screen, however in my code when the item is played all other items in the list also slide. I need only the touched item to slide on the screen.

My html code:

```
<ul id="menu-mobile">
        <li class="li-mobile hospital"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>Hospital</li>
        <li class="li-mobile especialidades"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>Especialidades</li>
        <li class="li-mobile exames"><i class="fa fa-stethoscope fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>Exames</li>
        <li class="li-mobile blog">Blog</li>
        <li class="li-mobile contato"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>Contato</li>
        <li class="li-mobile emergencia">Emergência</li>
    </ul>  



$(".li-mobile").click(function(e){
        if($(this).hasClass("toggle")) {
           $(this).removeClass('toggle').siblings().removeClass('toggle');
        }else{
            $(this).addClass('toggle').siblings().removeClass('toggle');
        }
    });
```

TKS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".li-mobile").click(function(e) {
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('toggle');

  if ($(this).hasClass("toggle")) {
     $(this).removeClass('toggle');
  } else {
     $(this).addClass('toggle');
  }
});
```

```css
#menu-mobile {
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 999;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
}

.li-mobile.hospital {
  background-color: #EEF463;
}

.li-mobile.especialidades {
  background-color: #E8B281;
}

.li-mobile.exames {
  background-color: #A2C8CA;
}

.li-mobile.blog {
  background-color: #CE737F;
}

.li-mobile.contato {
  background-color: #007969;
}

.li-mobile.emergencia {
  background-color: #CC2C69;
}

.li-mobile {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  right: -180px;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.li-mobile.toggle {
  right: 40px;
  margin-left: 66px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu-mobile">
  <li class="li-mobile"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>Hospital</li>
  <li class="li-mobile especialidades"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>Especialidades</li>
  <li class="li-mobile exames"><i class="fa fa-stethoscope fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>Exames</li>
  <li class="li-mobile blog">Blog</li>
  <li class="li-mobile contato"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>Contato</li>
  <li class="li-mobile emergencia">Emergência</li>
</ul>
```

The reason all the `li` were moving together is because of `position: fixed` for the ul. That is supposed to be `absolute` and the `li` is supposed to be `relative` for them to move independent of ul.

Comment: @scooby Can you post a snippet where you are able to reproduce the issue. Would be faster that way

Comment: I put it,  could you check it out?